# All the cases for Image and Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\pmatrix{
\alpha  & 1       & 1 & -1 \\
2       & -\alpha & 0 & -2 \\
-\alpha & 2       & 1 & 1
}$$

here alpha is a real variable, and I need to find the kernel and image for all values for alpha.

**Attempt:** I can't seem to figure out all the cases which I need to evaluate, as the last two columns are non-parallel - I've tried using this but to no avail. If someone could tell me the different cases to consider why that would be great, I'm sure I can from there work out the image and kernel. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two columns are linearly independent.  The first, third and fourth columns are linearly independent unless $\alpha = 1$.  Thus for $\alpha \ne 1$ the rank is $3$, the image is $\mathbb R^3$ and the kernel is one-dimensional.  For $\alpha = 1$ the rank turns out to be $2$, the image is two-dimensional, and the kernel is two-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Let's find the kernel:
$$
\alpha x_1 + x_2 + x_3 - x_4 = 0 \tag1
$$
$$
2x_1 - \alpha x_2 - 2x_4 = 0\tag2
$$
$$
-\alpha x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 0\tag3
$$
Add $(1)$ to $(3)$:
$$
3x_2 + 2x_3 = 0\Longrightarrow x_3=  -\frac32 x_2,
$$
and
$$
\alpha x_1 - x_4 = 0\tag{1'}
$$
$$
-\alpha x_1 + x_4 = 0\tag{3'}
$$
So, $x_4 = \alpha x_1$. Substitute into $(2)$:
$$
2x_1 - \alpha x_2 - 2\alpha x_1 = 0\Longrightarrow 2(1-\alpha)x_1 = \alpha x_2\Longrightarrow x_1 = \alpha t, x_2 = 2(1-\alpha)t
$$
Solution is $(\alpha t, 2(1-\alpha)t, 3(\alpha-1)t,\alpha^2 t)$, and
$$
\ker A = \mathop{\mathrm{span}} \{(\alpha, 2(1-\alpha), 3(\alpha-1),\alpha^2)\}
$$

Comment: First mistake is in adding (1) to (3): you should get $3 x_2 + 2 x_3 = 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, thanks, i'll edit